# Заменить в файле все первые буквы в словах на заглавные буквы

Tags: c++

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <locale>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<vcl.h>
#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char help[100];
int n;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian_russian");
FILE *f1, *f2;
printf("Input file name\n");
gets(help);
f1 = fopen(help, "rt");
if ((!f1)) {
printf("File not found!");
}
else
{
    f2 = fopen("File2.txt", "wt");
{
    while (fgets(help,99,f1))
{
    help[n] = toupper(help[n]);
    fprintf(f2, "%s", help);
}
}
getch();
return 0;
}
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

В первом файле у меня, допустим, есть строка "иван иванов", нужно, чтобы эта строка записалась во второй файл и при этом выглядела бы так: "Иван Иванов". Но проблема в том, что строка записывается во второй файл без изменений, то есть как было "иван иванов", так и осталось. 
То есть нужно, чтобы заменились в файле все первые буквы в словах на заглавные буквы. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Неправильный подход в строчке
    help[n] = toupper(help[n]);
Обрабатывается не вся строка текста, а только один символ, причем непонятно какой.

Comment: А что нужно в этой строчке прописать, чтобы первая буква слова приобрела верхний регистр?

Comment: А смысл? Здесь не занимаются решением учебных задач, но могут помочь, поэтому добавлю:

0. Включить свой мозг.

Comment: Вернее как написать на С++ выражение "Если первый символ строки имеет нижний регистр и символ после пробела также имеет нижний символ, то перевести их в верхний регистр"?
_____
    if (islower(help[0])) && (isspace(help[n+1]))
     {
       help[0] = toupper(help[0]);
       }

Написал условие, но здесь ошибка, напишите, пожалуйста, правильное условие или укажите, где ошибка.

Comment: @Luchfan12, Вам надо в цикле перебирать все символы введенной строки и переводить *подходящие*.

Что-то такое:

     for (int i = 0; help[i]; i++)
       if (islower(help[i]) && (i ? strchr(" \t.!?", help[i - 1]) : (char *)1))
         help[i] = toupper(help[i]);


Детали в `man isalpha`, `man strchr` и учебнике Си (например, K&R).


Будет ли работать с русскими буквами? -- зависит от того, как у Вас настроена локализация.

--

Посмотрел новую редакцию

       The value returned is that of the converted letter, or c if the conver‐
       sion was not possible.


Поэтому, действительно ...

Comment: (продолжение)

можно писать просто:

    for (int i = 0; help[i]; i++)
      if (!i || strchr(" \t.!?", help[i - 1]))
        help[i] = toupper(help[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо:

1. Пройти по всем символам строки от начала до конца.
2. Определить, является ли текущий символ первым в слове - он либо первый в строке, либо стоит после пробела, перевода строки и т.п.).
3. Если да, то перевести в верхний регистр (как в той строчке).

Поэтому нам нужен каждый i-й символ, который удовлетворяет условию п.2, его мы попробуем перевести в верхний регистр. Для упрощения предположим, что слова в строке разделяются только пробелами, знаков препинания и др. символов, кроме букв, нет. Тогда это условие может иметь вид:

```
if (i == 0 || help[i-1] == ' ')
    help[i] = toupper(help[i]);
```

т.е. если i=0, то help[i] первый символ строки, если help[i-1] == ' ', то текущему символу help[i] предшествует пробел. Только в этих случаях мы пытаемся его преобразовать.
Остается немного подпилить: поместить этот фрагмент в цикл со счетчиком i, чтобы пройти по всем символам от первого (i=0) до конца строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int n = 0; n<strlen(help); n++)
{
if((help[n-1]==' ') || (( n==0 ))
help[n] = toupper(help[n]);
}
```

Всё исправно работает!Если в первый файл ввести строку "иван иванов",то во втором файле выведется "Иван Иванов".

Comment: Только условие лучше записать вот так (как в моем ответе):

if(( n==0 ) || (help[n-1]==' '))

Операция || вычисляется по короткой схеме, т.е. если левый операнд = ИСТИНА, то правый не вычисляется. Это позволит не проверять символ help[-1]. Так более корректно.